# mysql is it possible to do insert into insert?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

what am doing is clonning an old database to new one with different structure but should have same old data

is it possible to do an **insert** into **insert** that return **id** of the insert query

```
INSERT INTO tab1 (nom,id_2) VALUES
("jack",(INSERT INTO tab2 (pass) VALUES ("1234")));
```

in `INSERT INTO tab2 (pass) VALUES ("1234")` i want to get the id of the insert

but no luck!! (i want it **in one sql query** (i already know about `mysql_insert_id`) )

thanks in advance

Comment: Why not have two separate statements? The first one will insert into tab2 and the second will use the same value and insert into tab1.

Comment: How about inserting the row on `tab2` and then use the `last_insert_id()` : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: quote: "A subquery is a SELECT statement within another statement." The [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/subqueries.html) site will explain how to use subqueries.

Comment: A subquery is just the mysql term for nested queries. My point was you can't have an insert inside another statement, you can only have a select nested inside another query. So disregarding php, there's no legal way of doing it in mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant do this on a single query - use [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to get the last inserted id for example :

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO tab2 (pass) VALUES ("1234")');
$lastid =  mysql_insert_id();
mysql_query('INSERT INTO tab1 (nom,id_2) VALUES ("jack",'.$lastid.')');
```

Comment: i only want it in one sql query (i already know about mysql_insert_id)

Comment: @mgraph im affraid you cant !

Answer (score 3):

insert id can be retrieved in mysql as well, so here is a version with no PHP involved (it however performs 2 queries)

```
INSERT INTO tab2 (pass) VALUES ("1234");
INSERT INTO tab1 (nom,id_2) VALUES("jack",LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Comment: @mgraph - and you're being told you can't... why do you __need__ it in one query?

Comment: @mgraph use multi-insert and it will generate sequential ids. Then get the first one, and increment it in the loop

Answer (score 1):

Lock the table, insert, select max(id), unlock table.  This is the only way outside creating your own sequence tables like in postgres if you are adverse for some reason to the last insert id functions.  This approach however is going to be like pouring tar into a blender if your table is moderate to high writes.

Comment: max(id) isn't quite so good if you have several concurrent database accesses... don't abuse your database, use mysql_insert_id();

Comment: @MarkBaker  It does create a logjam if multiple connections try to access the table, but it will reliably report the last ID you inserted if inside  a locked table.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this as a single insert because inserts are atomic that is, the ID isn't determined until the statement completes.

Wrap both statements in a transaction and you will get your ID, and atomicity.